# UILabel with Border and background Issue

Tags: swift, xcode, uilabel

Here is the code I have for UILabel

```
descriptionText.layer.cornerRadius     = 8
descriptionText.layer.borderColor      = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
descriptionText.layer.borderWidth      = 2
descriptionText.text                   = ""
descriptionText.layer.shadowOffset     = CGSize(width: -10, height: -10)
descriptionText.layer.shadowRadius     = -5.0
descriptionText.backgroundColor        = .white
descriptionText.textColor              = .black
descriptionText.numberOfLines          = 0
descriptionText.lineBreakMode          = .byWordWrapping
```

However This is what it looks like[image]

Why is the Corner Not Transparent  or how do you make what is outside the border transparent

Thanks in advance

Comment: try `descriptionText.clipsToBounds = true`

Comment: try `descriptionText.layer.masksToBounds = true` as well

Answer (score 1):

You need to hide everything outside of the cornerRadius by setting `.clipsToBounds` on the label to true. Problem is that if you do this you will lose the shadow, as this is outside the bounds as well. Try this:

Place your label inside a container view, constrain the label to the container edges, and create an outlet to it. Then try the following code:

```
containerView.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
containerView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
containerView.layer.borderWidth = 2
containerView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -10, height: -10)
containerView.layer.shadowRadius = -5.0
containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

descriptionText.text = "Testing"
descriptionText.cornerRadius = 8
descriptionText.clipsToBounds = true // or descriptionText.layer.masksToBounds = true
descriptionText.backgroundColor = .white
descriptionText.textColor = .black
descriptionText.numberOfLines = 0
descriptionText.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
```